# magento community forgot password not working

Tags: magento, forgot-password

I have inherited a Magento Community site, at some point in it's history it was upgraded and it seems that one of the upgrades did not successfully run Forgot Password SQL scripts. The `rp_token` and `rp_token_created_at` attributes are missing from the `eav_attribute` table.  So right now if you use the forgot password feature and enter in an email address that is in the system Magento throws an  error and you get a blank page.

I tried adding these fields in manually but Magento must be doing some extra work behind the scene when adding attributes, so my question is how can I run the upgrade scripts to get this feature working?

The scripts that it looks like did not complete successfully are:
`app\\code\\core\\Mage\\Customer\\sql\\customer_setup\\mysql4-upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.1.0.php`

These attributes are not in the eav_attribute table.

```
// Add reset password link token attribute
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'rp_token', array(
    'type'     => 'varchar',
    'input'    => 'hidden',
    'visible'  => false,
    'required' => false
));

// Add reset password link token creation date attribute
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'rp_token_created_at', array(
    'type'           => 'datetime',
    'input'          => 'date',
    'validate_rules' => 'a:1:{s:16:\"input_validation\";s:4:\"date\";}',
    'visible'        => false,
    'required'       => false
));
```

`app\\code\\core\\Mage\\Admin\\sql\\admin_setup\\upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.1.0.php`

These are not in the admin_user table.

```
// Add reset password link token column
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('admin/user'), 'rp_token', array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'length' => 256,
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null,
    'comment' => 'Reset Password Link Token'
));

// Add reset password link token creation date column
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('admin/user'), 'rp_token_created_at', array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null,
    'comment' => 'Reset Password Link Token Creation Date'
));'
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is SMTP could have been deactivated. Do let me know if am wrong.

Comment: It does not get that far, it throws a php error before it tries to send the send email.

Comment: Was your issue resolved. If not, kindly share the php error, please.